# Change Folder Permissions and All Sub-Folders

Tags: permissions, php, directory, ownership

I'm working on a `PHP` website at the moment and I'm doing a LOT of writing to files and directories.  Whenever these files are made, they're automatically owned by Daemon and I have to go into Terminal and execute
`sudo chown varosion /opt/lampp/htdocs/apps/<folder>` in order to edit or delete these files.  Is there anyway to take full ownership of the entire `lampp` folder and all future changes made to it?  If that's not possible, is there anyway to change `PHPs` default ownership?

EDIT: I just found the option "Change Permissions For Enclosed Files", I'm not sure if this has solved my problem but it sounds like it.

Comment: See the manual for chown. The -R options traverses subdirectories. And gui style: properties, change permissions for enclosed files

Answer (score 3):

Try `chmod -R xxx <files>` where xxx stands for your desired permissions for owner, group, and the rest of users.

The `-R` flag makes the result of the command to be recursive into the subfolders.

The `chown` command changes the owner of the files, the `chmod` fits better if you only want to change permissions.

Comment: Person in the comments beat you to it, I wish I could give the point to him.

Comment: That's another solution, his workaround is faster as you already were trying to use `chown`. You could also give it a try to `chmod`, you're not going to lose more than a few minutes testing, and I think it helps keep things tidy :-)